# Errors subprocess into jar file

Tags: python

i'm try to sign a file xml with a file **JAR** from **python(Django)**
to this i use the next code:

```
PATH_FIRMA_ABSOLUTA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'static/SRI/betty_elena_romo_vega.p12')


PATH_FIRMAR_JAVA = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'static/SRI/firmaXadesBes.jar')

file_pk12 = PATH_FIRMA_ABSOLUTA
password = 'Rgberv1792'
JAR_PATH = PATH_FIRMAR_JAVA
JAVA_CMD = 'java'
ds_document = False
#xml_str = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>"
PATH_XML_ABSOLUTO =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),path_xml_generado)
tree = etree.parse(str(PATH_XML_ABSOLUTO))
xml_str = etree.tostring(tree, encoding='utf8', method='xml')

command = [
    JAVA_CMD,
    '-jar',
    JAR_PATH,
    xml_str,
    base64.b64encode(file_pk12),
    base64.b64encode(password)
]

p = subprocess.Popen(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True
)
res = p.communicate()
```

i get this error:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...] (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...] (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
-d32\t  use a 32-bit data model if available
-d64\t  use a 64-bit data model if available
..
.
```

the error show when i try print :

```
 doc_signed = res[0]
print doc_signed
```

in this case JAR file return a string xml with a sign include but dont return on get the error.

thanks for any suggest.

Comment: which line you are getting this error?

Comment: the error is whe i try print the result "print res[0]"

Comment: Show the contents of the `command` list before you run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first install the 32-bit SDKor JRE and then select and install the 64-bit package on top of the 32-bit version. It probably means that, there is one entry point and that the selection is then done through -d32/-d64.